# Select MIN value on INNER JOIN

Tags: mysql, sqlsrv

I have some problem when selecting Minimum value. i have create inner join with 2 table and simple calculation in SQL query. Now i want to select minimum value from the calculation. here my query..

```
 $sql = "SELECT jobmatl_mst.item as item2,jobmatl_mst.u_m, job_mst.item, jobmatl_mst.job, jobmatl_mst.item as item2, jobmatl_mst.description, jobmatl_mst.matl_qty_conv , itemwhse_mst.item  as whseitem,itemwhse_mst.qty_on_hand, itemwhse_mst.qty_on_hand / jobmatl_mst.matl_qty_conv as total 
FROM job_mst 
INNER JOIN jobmatl_mst ON job_mst.job=jobmatl_mst.job 
INNER JOIN itemwhse_mst ON jobmatl_mst.item=itemwhse_mst.item 
WHERE job_mst.item ='601010944003' AND job_mst.type='S'
ORDER BY total";
```

i want to find minimum value for "total"..

Comment: Just add `limit 1` after the `order by`.

Comment: you'll want to look at [GROUP BY and Aggregate Functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html)

Comment: @GordonLinoff .. sorry sir, where can i put limit 1? i still amateur in SQL statement

Comment: something isn't right here.

Answer (score 0):

**Update:** The following solution is specific to MySQL.

---

The simplest answer that you can get that is close to your own code is to use `ORDER BY total LIMIT 1` at the end of your query.

```
$sql = "
    SELECT 
        jobmatl_mst.item as item2,
        jobmatl_mst.u_m, 
        job_mst.item, 
        jobmatl_mst.job, 
        jobmatl_mst.item as item2, 
        jobmatl_mst.description, 
        jobmatl_mst.matl_qty_conv , 
        itemwhse_mst.item  as whseitem,
        itemwhse_mst.qty_on_hand, 
        itemwhse_mst.qty_on_hand / jobmatl_mst.matl_qty_conv as total 
    FROM job_mst 
    INNER JOIN jobmatl_mst 
        ON job_mst.job=jobmatl_mst.job 
    INNER JOIN itemwhse_mst 
        ON jobmatl_mst.item=itemwhse_mst.item 
    WHERE 
        job_mst.item ='601010944003' AND 
        job_mst.type='S'
    ORDER BY total # Sort the result in a 
                   # way that lowest is first and highest is last
    LIMIT 1 # Then we need the first value
";
```

Usage of aggregate function `MIN()` and `group by` is also possible:

```
$sql = "
    SELECT 
        jobmatl_mst.item as item2,
        jobmatl_mst.u_m, 
        job_mst.item, 
        jobmatl_mst.job, 
        jobmatl_mst.item as item2, 
        jobmatl_mst.description, 
        jobmatl_mst.matl_qty_conv , 
        itemwhse_mst.item  as whseitem,
        itemwhse_mst.qty_on_hand, 
        MIN(itemwhse_mst.qty_on_hand / jobmatl_mst.matl_qty_conv) as min_total 
    FROM job_mst 
    INNER JOIN jobmatl_mst 
        ON job_mst.job=jobmatl_mst.job 
    INNER JOIN itemwhse_mst 
        ON jobmatl_mst.item=itemwhse_mst.item 
    WHERE 
        job_mst.item ='601010944003' AND 
        job_mst.type='S'
    GROUP BY
        jobmatl_mst.item as item2,
        jobmatl_mst.u_m, 
        job_mst.item, 
        jobmatl_mst.job, 
        jobmatl_mst.item as item2, 
        jobmatl_mst.description, 
        jobmatl_mst.matl_qty_conv , 
        itemwhse_mst.item  as whseitem,
        itemwhse_mst.qty_on_hand 
";
```

Note that in this case all the columns other than the one with aggregate function comes in the `GROUP BY` clause.

Comment: i try use LIMIT1 in sql server.. something isn't right near to limit... but i try aggregate function MIN(), the query is ok..

Comment: @MuhammadYusufAhmadShahRudd I am sorry, but the above query is specific to MySQL, not SQL Server

Comment: @MuhammadYusufAhmadShahRudd **In this situtation**, SQL Server equivalent of `LIMIT` is `TOP` and it is used just after `SELECT` like: `SELECT TOP 1 someValue ...`